# how to format currency in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have ajax data and want to change the format of numbers into currency, how to change the format? in php used `echo number_format($list->REAL_SUBPRO_VAL, 2, ',', '.')`, how about in ajax?

this is my ajax

```
function status(id_branch) {
    $('#status').show(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>home/list_investasi_status/" + id_branch,
            success(res){
                var data = JSON.parse(res);
                console.log(data);
                $('#nama_cabang3').text(data.data2['DISPLAY_NAME']);

                var data_status = "";

                $.each(data.data, function(key, val){
                    data_status += "<tr>\
                    <td>" + val.RKAP_INVS_ID + "</td>\
                    <td>" + val.RKAP_INVS_TITLE + "</td>\
                    <td>" + val.RKAP_INVS_COST_REQ + "</td>\
                    <td>" + val.RKAP_INVS_VALUE + "</td>\
                    <td>" + '<a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Detail</a>' + "</td>\
                    </tr>";

                });

                $('#show_status').html(data_status);

                /*dropdown*/
                var d_status = "";

                $.each(data.data3, function(key, val){
                    d_status += "<option >" + val.STATUS_NAME + "</option>";

                });

                // value="val.STATUS_NAME"
                $('#show_d_status').html(d_status);
            }
        })

    });
```

example: `val.RKAP_INVS_VALUE = 10000000`, i want to format value to `1.000.000`. help please thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the javascript splice method to insert a . into the string at the places you need. Here is the function doing it:

Moreover, you can use the php method number_format($list->REAL_SUBPRO_VAL, 2, ',', '.') and return your data in JSON so you will get a preformatted text.

```js
var main = '1000000';
var ins = '.';

insert = function insert(main_string, ins_string, pos) {
    if (typeof(pos) == "undefined") {
        pos = 0;
    }
    if (typeof(ins_string) == "undefined") {
        ins_string = '';
    }
    return main_string.slice(0, pos) + ins_string + main_string.slice(pos);
}
var newstring = insert(main, ins, 1);
alert(insert(newstring, ins, 5));
```